# What does that mean by Cobol error code: 243?

Tags: oop, cobol

I got the error when running the Cobol program in Micro Focus Cobol Eclipse. Don't know why this happened. Please help me as I have to submit this as a part of my big homework tommorrow.
Another question, if possible, please help me with the variable, I am putting it in local-storage section. for example, in Java, I want to set it as global for every method to get access?

The control file :

```
   Identification Division.
    Program-Id. Client.
    Environment Division.
    Configuration Section.
    Repository.
    Class Student.

    Data Division.
    Working-Storage Section.
    01 H object reference Student.

    Procedure Division.

        display "goodbye goodbye".                
        Invoke Student "new" returning H.
        Invoke H "sayHello".
        Invoke H "GetAverage" .
        Invoke H "Grading".

    Exit Program.
    End Program Client.
```

Here is the class file:

```
   class-id. Student data is protected 
  *            inherits from base with data
   inherits Base.

   object section.
   class-control.
       Student is class "student"
       base is class "base"
       .
   working-storage section.


   class-object.
   object-storage section.

   Method-Id. sayHello.
    Procedure Division.
            Display "Hello World!".
  *         Display "I'm hello".
    End Method sayHello.


  *Method1
   method-id. "GetAverage".
   local-storage section.

   linkage section.
   01 English  pic 99 value 9.
   01 Math     pic 99 value 5.
   01 AverMark pic 99 value 3.
   procedure division using by reference English,
                               by reference Math.
  *                            returning AverMark.

       COMPUTE AverMark = (English+Math)/2
       Display "Average mark is ", AverMark.
       Accept English.
   exit method.
   end method "GetAverage".

  *Method2
   method-id. "Grading"
   local-storage section.

   linkage section.
   01 AverMark pic 9.
   01 Grade pic X.
   procedure division using by reference AverMark.
  *                            returning Grade.

   IF AverMark < 5 
       MOVE "FAIL" TO Grade
   ELSE 
       MOVE "PASS" TO Grade.

   exit method.
   end method "Grading".

   end class-object.

   end class Student.
```

The result is:

goodbye goodbye

Execution error : file 'Client'
error code: 243, pc=0, call=1, seg=0
243      error message text not found

Comment: I finally found out the mistakes. thank you everyone :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation on the Micro Focus site an error 243 is explained as follows ..

"COBRT243 Class could not be loaded (Fatal)

An attempt to load an object class has failed because the class does not contain a valid Class-Control section, or because the class is not defined correctly."

Check that you've defined Student properly.

Comment: could you suggest me how to fix it? I'm beginner to Cobol